# matlab replace number

Tags: matlab

in a column, value 2 replace with 1 and value 1 & 3 replace with 2. The code i wrote below got problem:

```
S=[1 1 1 2 2 3 3 3 3];
S(S==2)=1; S(S==1)=2; S(S==3)=2;
```

result:

```
S=[2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2]
```

However, the result i wan to get is S=[2 2 2 1 1 2 2 2 2]. does anyone can help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is happening because when in the `S(S==1)=2;` step, you are affected by the modifications from the `S(S==2)=1;` step. Try this

```
S = [1 1 1 2 2 3 3 3 3];
S_copy = S;
S(S_copy == 2) = 1; S(S_copy == 1) = 2; S(S_copy == 3) = 2;
```

or you could also save the results of the tests into separate variables:

```
S = [1 1 1 2 2 3 3 3 3];
f1 = (S == 2);
f2 = (S == 1);
f3 = (S == 3);
S(f1) = 1; S(f2) = 2; S(f3) = 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of manually replacing each value, you can use an extra matrix to define a "map" from input values in S to output values.

```
>> S = [1 1 1 2 2 3 3 3 3];  % input
>> M = [2 1 2];              % M[i] = j -> map value i to j
>> S = M(S)                  % compute output
S =
     2     2     2     1     1     2     2     2     2
```

This operation should be really fast in Matlab.

Note that this methods works as long as the values in S can be interpreted as index values (that is, they are integers and not too large).

Answer (score -1):

your are getting closer but the problem arises once you change all the 2's to one.
after this statement
`S(S==2)=1;`
the array looks like this
S=[1 1 1 1 1 3 3 3 3];
and after the other two statements `S(S==1)=2; S(S==3)=2;`
your array will obviously have all 2's.

Instead of 
`S(S==2)=1; S(S==1)=2; S(S==3)=2;`

you can do like this:

`S(S==2)=-1; S(S==1)=2; S(S==3)=2;S(S==-1)=1;`

i.e. in the first step change all the `2`'s to some other value(e.g. `-1` here) and then do the required conversion i.e. `S(S==-1)=1`;